# Vector Color function usage

Tags: plotting, color, vector

Can anyone explain why there is a difference between following plots:

```
VectorPlot[{-y, x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 VectorScale -> {0.05, Automatic, None}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 4}}][n]], 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

and[image]

```
VectorPlot[{-y, x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 VectorScale -> {0.05, Automatic, None}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
   ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 4}}][Norm[{vx, vy}]]], 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

In the documentation it is said that fifth argument of VectorColorFunction is just Norm[{vx, vy}] so the plots should coincide?

Comment: try `Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Norm[{vx, vy}]]]` or `Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
 ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 4}}][4 Norm[{vx, vy}]]]`?

Comment: Yes, this works! Can you explain why I need to multiply the norm by 4 to obtain a similar plot?

Comment: @AlexanderNikolaenko Notice first that your coloring matches, roughly, that of the region {{-1,-1},{1,1}}, and so when you specify the range of the ColorData, and do not properly scale the `Norm` which you are then taking & applying the color function to, then you get the output you show above. However, we cannot know for sure how to fix this problem, as we (SE folks) do not have any definitions of the vector functions & variables to test this on. Can you assist with that? Many thanks!